# How can I use Selenium with Python3 and xpath to click on an image in an html table?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-table

How can I use Selenium with Python3 and xpath to click on an image in an html table? The webpage I'm using is: http://www.swissdock.ch/docking. The image I want to click on using Selenium is the green plus sign that shows up when a pdb code is entered in the Target selection Search. When I right clicked on the image, Select, and then Copy Xpath, the Xpath is: 
  //*[@id="example"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/img

The code I have used to try this is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver

# This section is my working code
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver1.get("http://www.swissdock.ch/docking")
inputElementc = driver1.find_element_by_id("DockingTargetSearch")
inputElementc.send_keys('4gu6')
linka = driver1.find_element_by_id('target_search_submit')
linka.click()

#This section is my code that doesn't work
button = driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='example']/tbody/tr/td[1]/img")
button.click()
```

Besides the code above, I have followed numerous other examples without success. I have also found similar examples, but for java and Python2, which I was unable to translate into Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task of clicking the green button using Selenium is complicated by it being located within a table, which I'm told is bad web development practice; tables should be used for data.

Take a different approach to the task. The website in question has an alternative to Search Target selection, in which the user can upload a file. Download the target file that you were going to search for from the pdb database. Modify the target file with a molecular modeling program such as Chimera to delete extra chains.

Then, delete the Selenium code for doing the target search, and replace it with code for uploading the target file that was downloaded from the database (the following four lines)

```
linkb = driver1.find_element_by_id('link_target_upload')
linkb.click()
linkz = driver1.find_element_by_id('DockingTargetUpload')
linkz.send_keys('/path/filename')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this syntax in Python3

```
ActionChains(driver1).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

However looking at your html table the challenge is that it pulls up the image reference multiple times in the table, since it's referenced once but repeated so figuring out how to specify the row will be key.

Comment: I haven't been able to click this image yet, but I have now successfully used ActionChains to do other things I was trying to do, so thank you for that.